# Get recently viewed posts by using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store and display recently viewed posts. I don't want to use cookies because not only want to show what the visitor him/her self viewed posts but viewed by others as well.

I know I can simply store post id in the table and display the data. But is this is best way to do this. As I understand this will store huge amount of junk data in the database as I only want to display 10 latest viewed posts on my website.

Can anyone tell me a better way to do this or is this the only way to do this?

Comment: If you only will show the last 10 posts viewed by any user, you could create a table that only will hold 10 records as a maximum. You would then update this table changing the post_id whenever a user first displays a post.

Comment: You may store "last-viewed datetime" for each post and display 10 most recently viewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "dt_lastViewed" field to your "Posts" table. Update it when it's been viewed, and pull the top 10 for your module.

Optionally, create another field called "timesViewed" so that you can increment and track the most popular posts! *May be considered [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)*